# Automatically inserted rows in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, rdbms, jobs

I am quite new in SQL Server, so i'll ask my question directly:

Let's say I have two tables

- `A` (a1 type1, ..., ai DATE, frequence INT, ...,aN typeN)

  - `frequence` represents the number of days
- `B` (b1 type1,..., bi typei, ...., bN typeN)

What I want to do is to put a kind of listener on the table A that listens the ''ai and frequence'' attributes of each row, and then inserts rows into the table B, example :

1. (v1, ...., "2016-03-01",30, ....,vN) a row of table A, so a new row is added to the table B every month beginning from  the date "2016-03-01"

So a new row is inserted in the table B on : "2016-04-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-06-01" and so on.

2. the new inserted B row can be calculated according on information contained in Table A (insert is just an example of a process)

I've already looked for this question, and the most relevant answer that I found is to use triggers, but triggers are fired after or instead of an `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` and those operations are hard coded, it's not the DBMS (or the current date in the example above) that initiate the process, it's the client.

Every remark is welcome.

Thank you, and see you soon below.

Comment: Hi El Barto, welcome to SO, good question (in terms of format/rules).

Comment: It is not clear why you are not willing to use Trigger

Comment: it is not really initate by client. The client merely insert rows into the table A. Table Triggers created on Table A will fire the Trigger and insert rows into table B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a scheduled job because you don't want the rows to be inserted into table B at the time they are inserted into A.  The scheduled job can call a stored procedure or execute the SQL query directly.

Here's the syntax for [creating a stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BuildBFromA
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Numbers TABLE
    (
         Number int Primary Key
    )

    --You get the idea
    INSERT into @Numbers
    VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3)

    --Put your insert query here.
    insert B (b1, bi, bN)
    Select a1, a1, aN
    from a
    join @Numbers n on 1=1
    where DATEADD(a.aN,n.Number,a.ai) = convert(date,getdate())
END
GO
```

Here's the syntax for [adding a scheduled job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx):

```
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'Build B' ;
GO
EXEC sp_add_jobstep
    @job_name = N'Build B',
    @step_name = N'Insert Rows in B based on A',
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',
    @command = N'EXECUTE BuildBFromA', 
    @retry_attempts = 5,
    @retry_interval = 5 ;
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_schedule
    @schedule_name = N'RunEveryMinute',
    @freq_type = 4,
    @active_start_time = 233000;
USE msdb ;
GO
EXEC sp_attach_schedule
   @job_name = N'Build B',
   @schedule_name = N'RunEveryMinute';
GO
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver
    @job_name = N'Build B';
GO
```

Normally I would create an example on [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com), but the site doesn't seem to be working now.

Comment: thanks my dear freind, that's the word "job/listener". I 'm looking for a way to attach a "job" that checks every row of A, and then decide if any condition is verified (in the scenario that i gave : ( inDays(currentDate - A.ai) % A.frequence = 0 )

Comment: sorry it's my first question in SO, I didn't knew that edition of comments are allowed for only 5 minutes. so I'll continue my comment :

 when the condition is verified, the job does a processe in table B using the information of the row (in A) that "fires" the job

Comment: I don't know a way to exactly attach a job to a table.  But, using a job and a proc you can run a query that will act on information in table A to affect table B.  It's not pretty because the job won't have any intelligence to it.  It will just run on whatever schedule you set for it.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger would work fine in this scenario. The trigger does fire at the database level, that means it can not be bypassed by the client. This seems to be what you want as all inserts to this table will be caught by the trigger. If a client inserts a record into Table A then the trigger will automatically fire and insert the relevant record into Table B based on your logic. I dont know your full logic, you would need to check the months etc and make sure that they don't exist yet etc. I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader. The thing to note is that a virtual table called "inserted" exists which you can check, this includes all rows that were just inserted into table A.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertNewMonth
   ON  A
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert B (b1, bi, bN)
    Select a1, a1, aN
    from inserted
END
GO
```

Comment: In this scenario, a trigger won't be able to do the trick, because I want the process to be done after a given time, NOT just after an INSERT/DELETE or UPDATE on the table A

.thank you